# How to disable menu in Blackberry default browser

Tags: browser, blackberry, menu, items

I have to launch default blackberry browser in my application and display html page. But i do not want browser default menu items. I want to either disable default menu items or make them not selectable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't supress the default MenuItems in the native browser application. You'll need to implement a [BrowserField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Configure_a_browser_field_825671_11.jsp) in your own application instead.